FluentAssertions `.Should().BeEquivalentTo` which property failed?
`I am trying to compare two complex objects and the output from the test generates the same Json but the test fails. How can I tell which properties are causing the failure?
This is the complete log from the failed test. I can't tell which property failed
            am.Should()
                .BeEquivalentTo(ms, options =>
                {
                    return options
                        .WithTracing()
                        .WithAutoConversion()
                        //I've set `CompareByValue` for the complex properties.
                        .ComparingByValue<IEarTag>()
                        .ComparingByValue<InternationalId>()
                        .ComparingByValue<StrippedEarTag>()
                        .ComparingByValue<DamSummaryDTO>()
                        .ComparingByValue<SireSummaryDTO>();
                });

Result Trace
  Message: 
    Expected am to be HukNetCore.Common.AnimalDTO
    {
        AICode = "020d1b", 
        AmsHerdID = 8, 
        AmsReference = 33, 
        AnimalId = 211, 
        AnimalName = "0d9dcb24-6bc8-4365-a079-c20457284d49", 
        BcmsEartag = "9abd2475-bf0c-46d2-a548-f3867f119804", 
        Breed = "Breed16e3f399-d599-491f-a3e9-bcc814390526", 
        BreederCustomerNo = 184, 
        CalvingDifficulty = "5", 
        DLC = "DLC1f1d539e-62d2-44b7-ade9-f801ebfb87dd", 
        DLCMct = "DLCMctdc9bde73-74f5-4a90-8d27-967c7f6ee989", 
        DNA = "0791e2c1-8e83-4c58-8", 
        DOB = "236bc7ec", 
        DairyGroupID = 236s, 
        Dam = HukNetCore.Common.Animal.DamSummaryDTO
        {
            Breed = "e4", 
            HBN = "d075757c-1cf", 
            HBNFlag = "d", 
            Id = 254, 
            Name = "37358d37-ba35-4e9a-aac0-17c3a19db1b2", 
            SRCode = "03", 
            SocietyId = SocietyEnum.Undefined {value: 0}
        }, 
        DardEarTag = "36f346f1-0ec0-43e5-9097-e8aff4035fd9", 
        DateDied = <2022-08-16 08:45:06.6023536>, 
        DateOfBirth = <2024-06-09 13:43:13.4681712>, 
        DateOfLastCalving = <2022-10-24 07:32:18.6929075>, 
        DateOfLastChange = <2025-08-16 09:35:53.4438397>, 
        DateOfRegistration = <2022-08-26 04:38:35.8780933>, 
        DateOfService = <2024-01-04 23:35:56.150558>, 
        Dead = "d", 
        ETCollectionDate = <2023-07-06 14:18:37.388159>, 
        ETRef = "511d8d90-e83", 
        EarMark = "eac1d7b0-1158-4555-8500-7d68ff51275f", 
        EarTag = "GeneralTests.AnimalMappingTests+FakeEarTag", 
        EtCollId = 251, 
        EvaluationGroup = 68s, 
        HBN = "9dcfce37-392", 
        HBNFlag = aHBNFlag.H {value: 0}, 
        HerdPrefix = "60cd1c38-eb22-477a-834e-c50e4f", 
        ISOBreedCode = "ISOBreedCode506e2fcf-c093-418b-9149-1d005979aaf7", 
        ISOCountry = "ISOCountry009fed5f-af67-491f-988a-eb7388906047", 
        InternationalID = BreedIsoCodee8d77aa1-3e4c-426e-9cab-e78e744eec6cSex03880ebd-7c47-4b3e-b46c-08289cddafc3Hbn7e1adc39-1d31-4263-9b67-fd2e0f05afc7, 
        LineNo = "ec3dbeac-cb0f-4f41-8", 
        MasterRecord = "d", 
        OrigSource = 0x8D, 
        OwnerCustomerNo = 225, 
        PCHol = 92s, 
        PCPure = 191s, 
        PIMkr = "12", 
        Prefix = "Prefixe9b76335-2b8b-4573-9572-f506f1bdfae8", 
        RedMarker = "c", 
        SRCode = "23", 
        SerialNo = "5db6", 
        ServiceType = "46", 
        Sex = "Null", 
        SexCode = "04", 
        Sire = HukNetCore.Common.Animal.SireSummaryDTO
        {
            Breed = "26", 
            HBN = "1a831fed-0f1", 
            HBNFlag = "e", 
            Id = 183, 
            Initials = "7836a", 
            Name = "ee3966f6-7750-4733-be8c-7280005c3193", 
            SRCode = "0b", 
            SocietyId = SocietyEnum.HOLSTEINUK {value: 1}
        }, 
        SocietyId = SocietyEnum.JERSEY {value: 2}, 
        StrippedEarTag = HukNetCore.Common.Animal.StrippedEarTag
        {
            Value = "e6fdfd31d11a840998d00fc1cf0d27f8c"
        }, 
        TwinCode = "9f4", 
        XBred = "b"
    }, but found HukNetCore.Common.AnimalDTO
    {
        AICode = "020d1b", 
        AmsHerdID = 8, 
        AmsReference = 33, 
        AnimalId = 211, 
        AnimalName = "0d9dcb24-6bc8-4365-a079-c20457284d49", 
        BcmsEartag = "9abd2475-bf0c-46d2-a548-f3867f119804", 
        Breed = "Breed16e3f399-d599-491f-a3e9-bcc814390526", 
        BreederCustomerNo = 184, 
        CalvingDifficulty = "5", 
        DLC = "DLC1f1d539e-62d2-44b7-ade9-f801ebfb87dd", 
        DLCMct = "DLCMctdc9bde73-74f5-4a90-8d27-967c7f6ee989", 
        DNA = "0791e2c1-8e83-4c58-8", 
        DOB = "236bc7ec", 
        DairyGroupID = 236s, 
        Dam = HukNetCore.Common.Animal.DamSummaryDTO
        {
            Breed = "e4", 
            HBN = "d075757c-1cf", 
            HBNFlag = "d", 
            Id = 254, 
            Name = "37358d37-ba35-4e9a-aac0-17c3a19db1b2", 
            SRCode = "03", 
            SocietyId = SocietyEnum.Undefined {value: 0}
        }, 
        DardEarTag = "36f346f1-0ec0-43e5-9097-e8aff4035fd9", 
        DateDied = <2022-08-16 08:45:06.6023536>, 
        DateOfBirth = <2024-06-09 13:43:13.4681712>, 
        DateOfLastCalving = <2022-10-24 07:32:18.6929075>, 
        DateOfLastChange = <2025-08-16 09:35:53.4438397>, 
        DateOfRegistration = <2022-08-26 04:38:35.8780933>, 
        DateOfService = <2024-01-04 23:35:56.150558>, 
        Dead = "d", 
        ETCollectionDate = <2023-07-06 14:18:37.388159>, 
        ETRef = "511d8d90-e83", 
        EarMark = "eac1d7b0-1158-4555-8500-7d68ff51275f", 
        EarTag = "GeneralTests.AnimalMappingTests+FakeEarTag", 
        EtCollId = 251, 
        EvaluationGroup = 68s, 
        HBN = "9dcfce37-392", 
        HBNFlag = aHBNFlag.H {value: 0}, 
        HerdPrefix = "60cd1c38-eb22-477a-834e-c50e4f", 
        ISOBreedCode = "ISOBreedCode506e2fcf-c093-418b-9149-1d005979aaf7", 
        ISOCountry = "ISOCountry009fed5f-af67-491f-988a-eb7388906047", 
        InternationalID = BreedIsoCodee8d77aa1-3e4c-426e-9cab-e78e744eec6cSex03880ebd-7c47-4b3e-b46c-08289cddafc3Hbn7e1adc39-1d31-4263-9b67-fd2e0f05afc7, 
        LineNo = "ec3dbeac-cb0f-4f41-8", 
        MasterRecord = "d", 
        OrigSource = 0x8D, 
        OwnerCustomerNo = 225, 
        PCHol = 92s, 
        PCPure = 191s, 
        PIMkr = "12", 
        Prefix = "Prefixe9b76335-2b8b-4573-9572-f506f1bdfae8", 
        RedMarker = "c", 
        SRCode = "23", 
        SerialNo = "5db6", 
        ServiceType = "46", 
        Sex = "Null", 
        SexCode = "04", 
        Sire = HukNetCore.Common.Animal.SireSummaryDTO
        {
            Breed = "26", 
            HBN = "1a831fed-0f1", 
            HBNFlag = "e", 
            Id = 183, 
            Initials = "7836a", 
            Name = "ee3966f6-7750-4733-be8c-7280005c3193", 
            SRCode = "0b", 
            SocietyId = SocietyEnum.HOLSTEINUK {value: 1}
        }, 
        SocietyId = SocietyEnum.JERSEY {value: 2}, 
        StrippedEarTag = HukNetCore.Common.Animal.StrippedEarTag
        {
            Value = "e6fdfd31d11a840998d00fc1cf0d27f8c"
        }, 
        TwinCode = "9f4", 
        XBred = "b"
    }.
    
    With configuration:
    - Use declared types and members
    - Compare enums by value
    - Compare tuples by their properties
    - Compare anonymous types by their properties
    - Compare records by their members
    - Compare HukNetCore.Common.Animal.IEarTag by value
    - Compare HukNetCore.Common.InternationalId by value
    - Compare HukNetCore.Common.Animal.StrippedEarTag by value
    - Compare HukNetCore.Common.Animal.DamSummaryDTO by value
    - Compare HukNetCore.Common.Animal.SireSummaryDTO by value
    - Include non-browsable members
    - Match member by name (or throw)
    - Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays
    - Try conversion of all members. 
    
    With trace:
      am
      {
        Treating am as a value type because HukNetCore.Common.AnimalDTO overrides Equals.
        Equivalency was proven by ValueTypeEquivalencyStep
      }
    

  Stack Trace: 
    LateBoundTestFramework.Throw(String message)
    TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
    CollectingAssertionStrategy.ThrowIfAny(IDictionary`2 context)
    EquivalencyValidator.AssertEquality(Comparands comparands, EquivalencyValidationContext context)
    ObjectAssertions`2.BeEquivalentTo[TExpectation](TExpectation expectation, Func`2 config, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
    AnimalMappingTests.AnimalBase_DTO() line 41

Need to get around the post error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." so adding random text.
